# create sequence on pydev for postgres database

Tags: python, eclipse, postgresql, pydev, pgadmin-4

I am trying to generate random numbers from 90001 to 90150 (increments of one) under a column "GameID" and have it generated in the games table. What should I do? I heard a sequence might work but I am not sure how this would work. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count, cycle
from _tkinter import create
from setuptools.dist import sequence
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    firstline = 1
    con = None
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE games")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE teams")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE referees")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE games (HomeTeamID VARCHAR, HomeTeam VARCHAR, AwayTeamID VARCHAR, AwayTeam VARCHAR, FTHG INTEGER, ATHG INTEGER, FTR VARCHAR, RefereeID VARCHAR, RefereeName VARCHAR, HY INTEGER, AY INTEGER)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE teams (HomeTeamID VARCHAR, HomeTeam VARCHAR, AwayTeamID VARCHAR, AwayTeam VARCHAR)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Referees (RefereeID VARCHAR, RefereeName VARCHAR)")
    create sequence sq_demo
    start with 10001
    increment by 1
    maxvalue 15000
    minvalue 10001
    cache 3
    cycle
    order;

    try:
        for row in readCSV:
            if firstline:
                firstline=0
                continue 
            HomeTeamID = row[2]
            HomeTeam = row[2]
            AwayTeamID = row[3]
            AwayTeam = row[3]
            FTHG = row[4]
            ATHG = row[5]
            FTR = row[6]
            RefereeID = row[10]
            RefereeName = row[10]
            HY = row[19]
            AY = row[20]
            data1 = (HomeTeamID, HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam, FTHG, ATHG, FTR, RefereeID, RefereeName, HY, AY)
            data2 = (HomeTeamID, HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam)
            data3 = (RefereeID, RefereeName)
            query1 = "INSERT INTO games (HomeTeamID , HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam, FTHG, ATHG, FTR, RefereeID, RefereeName, HY, AY) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
            query2 = "INSERT INTO teams (HomeTeamID , HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
            query3 = "INSERT INTO Referees (RefereeID, RefereeName) VALUES (%s, %s);"
            print(HomeTeam)
            print(AwayTeam)
            print (FTHG)
            print (ATHG)
            print (FTR)
            print (RefereeID)
            print (RefereeName)
            print (HY)
            print (AY)
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query1, data1)
            cursor.execute(query2, data2)
            cursor.execute(query3, data3)
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        if con:
            con.rollback() 
            print ("Error %s % e", e)
            sys.exit(1) 
    finally:
        if con:
            con.commit()
            con.close()

print(" ".join(row))
out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in data1:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to generate random numbers from 90001 to 90150 (increments
>   of one) under a column "GameID" and have it generated in the games
>   table

It doesn't look like a sequence is needed here.
You could run this query:

```
select i from generate_series(90001, 90150) as x(i) order by random()
```

and pick a result from it at each game inserted in the loop.